# Antonym for "Virgin"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What's an antonym for "virgin"? A single word would be preferable.

Comment: Could not it be _pregnant_?

Comment: @kiamlaluno There are plenty of people out there that are neither virgin nor pregnant. Some of them can't get pregnant at all (mostly men).

Comment: @Cyril I was not being serious; I was simply joking. Is there really a reason to use a single word to say "I am not virgin anymore"?

Comment: For those few so far who have voted to close, how is this possibly subjective or argumentative? If it is, then -any- word-suggestion is such.

Comment: "most widely understood" is subjective and impossible to answer

Comment: @nohat, it's not any more subjective than the vast majority of the other single-word-request questions that we get. Very many of those questions ask for something like the "best" or "most understood" word, and I've never seen any other question closed for that reason. At worst you can just edit the question to remove the offending wordage.

Comment: All the ones I can think of other than deflowered are generally considered offensive... sorry

Comment: Among Nerdfighters, the word is *virgout*.

Comment: Do you mean a non-virgin, or an "anti-virgin" (like a person with hundreds of sex partners)?

Comment: "former virgin"

Comment: How do you define a *virgin*? Medically? Ethically? Socially? Colloquially? Lexically? Otherwise? Perhaps, compassionately?

Comment: [Relevant?](http://youtube.com/watch?v=5LpHfPOM6GQ)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is OP's second question on EL&U, and the [previous one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28817/word-to-describe-quality-of-being-a-blind-study) refers to the fact that he's *"writing an application that deals with blind studies"*. In light of that, I assume OP is effectively looking for a medical term.

I'm not a doctor, but [these people](http://www.sogc.org/jogc/abstracts/full/201104_WomensHealth_1.pdf) are, and they use the term **coitally experienced**. Here's an [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=coitally%20experienced&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5) showing they're not alone.

In case anyone objects that (besides not being single-word) *coitally experienced* applies to males as well as females, I suggest **post-coitarchal** or perhaps my own neologism **coitarchated** (which I think would be well enough understood on first encounter by people working in that area).

**Coitarche** [(first experience of full intercourse)](http://books.google.com/books?id=mEsPakNJWZYC&pg=PA15&dq=%22coitarche%22%20%2bfirst&hl=en&ei=FvfuTf3QBIncgQeWrJ2VDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&sqi=2&ved=0CGEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22coitarche%22%20%2bfirst&f=false) didn't really enter the lexicon until the early '80s, but it's clearly formed by association with [menarche](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/menarche) (a pubescent girl's first period), so I think that's good enough to say *coitarche* and derivatives relate more to the female than the male side of the experience.

Comment: +1 and here's a _coitarche_ [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=mEsPakNJWZYC&pg=PA15&dq=%22coitarche%22+%2Bfirst&hl=en&ei=FvfuTf3QBIncgQeWrJ2VDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&sqi=2&ved=0CGEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22coitarche%22%20%2Bfirst&f=false).

Comment: If the OP is a doctor or similar, I think your term "coitarchated" would be perfect for when the doctors want to speak in front of a patient and not have them understand.  And when they want to ask the question of the patient, they'll need to say, "Are you sexually experienced?".  I'm loving the image of a patient being asked, "Are you coitarchated?"  I can tell you the answer; it's no.

Comment: @Julia: Well, my coinage certainly isn't making much headway! It's currently the one-word equivalent of a [Googlewhack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googlewhack), in that I just searched for it, and this answer is the only occurrence! So now I'm wishing you hadn't just told me the answer - if you'd kept shtum I would have been able to pose a question ELU: *"Is Julia coitarchated?"* and at a stroke doubled the word's internet presence! :)

Comment: I feel that to some degree, "post-coitarchal" suggests "immediately after" the first experience, not the rest of one's life; just as "post-coital" refers to the period immediately after coitus (maybe half an hour or so), not the remainder of one's existence.

Comment: @David Wallace: I think you're probably being unduly influenced by *"post-coital"*, which is so common that even the [post-coital cigarette](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22post-coital+cigarette%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets nearly 2000 hits in Google Books (and over a hundred times as many on Google Internet). You'd hardly say *post-menopausal* only lasted for a short time, would you?

Comment: Interesting comment @FumbleFingers (and I just triangled it).  I guess the prefix post- doesn't always mean the same thing.  So if you maintain that post-coitarchal means "any time after the first experience", what word would you use to mean for "immediately after the first experience", at least in post-coital timeframe?

Comment: @David Wallace: I don't really know. I'm just saying *post-menopausal post-marital*, etc., would normally be understood to refer to *the rest of your life* after that period/event. I don't see why you'd expect English to have special words for the short period immediately after one-off events like this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ... Wouldn't *coitarched* mean *deflowered*?

Comment: @AnWulf: Well, yes. But *deflowered* is hopelessly archaic / poetic / euphemistic - even somewhat sexist, imho. And I did start off by implying I should assume OP wanted something clinical / modern / neutral, because his previous question related to something like a "medical trials" database.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ... Actually, I was thinking more along the line that *to coitarche* would mean *to have sex the first time* (thus deflowered) (coitus=sexual intercourse, arche=beginning) ... to begin to have sex ... thereafter, the person would be *coitized*. I guess both would work. coitarched would mean that the person is no longer a virgin ... as would coitized.

Comment: @AnWulf: I see what you mean, in that *coitized* could indeed be interpreted that way. But for example, if someone asks you *"have you drunk alcohol?"* they probably don't mean *"ever in your life"* - they're more likely to mean *"quite recently, such that the experience is still fresh (and maybe you're still intoxicated right now)"*. By the same token, I would tend to interpret *coitized* as meaning *still flushed from the recent experience*, whereas I wouldn't see the same "immediacy" connotation in *coitarchated/[post-]coitarchal*.

Comment: Can only girls be deflowered, not boys?

Comment: @tchrist: [Apparently not](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22deflowered+boys%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: May I suggest that you may have simply asked a suboptimal question?  [Try this one](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22deflowered+boys%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22deflowered+him%22&oq=%22deflowered+him%22&gs_l=serp.3...2958.3479.0.3771.3.3.0.0.0.0.72.178.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.ISQsNC4zRIc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=d25b2fdb394bb867&bpcl=37189454&biw=1916&bih=1068). Lots of deflowering of “hims” [sic] going on there. And it seems it can be done by a female, or by a male, too.

Comment: Here’s a ♀-to-♂ example: “She was the one who deflowered him and introduced him to sex.”  And here’s a ♂-to-♂ example: “For because Archelaus deflowered him and then persistently refused to return him to his home as promised, he thought that the king's sexual relations with him were 15 motivated by arrogance rather than sexual desire.”

Comment: @tchrist: Again, I think just two instances are sufficient to make the point - [**she** deflowered **him**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22she+deflowered+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your statement — which was perfectly clear. My fault, not yours. BTW, the OED2 has an *unvirgin* verb and an *unvirgined* ppl. adj. from way back in the 17th century, plus in their 1Q2010 update, they added the verb *revirginize*. I have no idea how any of that works; I should have thought an *unvirgin* were the antonym of the noun *virgin*; I am astonished to find that it actually a verb.

Comment: @tchrist It is sometimes referred to as "hymen reconstruction" or "hymen repair". It is an elective procedure. I kid you not. On a separate but related matter, I am laughing so much at your (and Fumble's) deflowering search link results. I nearly typed "deforest" by mistake.

Answer (score 12):

Try **deflowered**.

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deflower):

> deflower
>
> 1. to deprive of virginity, esp by rupturing the hymen through sexual
>      intercourse
> 2. to despoil of beauty, innocence, etc.; mar; violate

Though, some might argue that this is exclusively feminine, I might beg to differ.

Comment: This has an immediacy to it that doesn't carry on through life, I think. Your 80-year-old grandmother is obviously not a virgin, but would you use the term "deflowered" to describe her? I think not.

Comment: _Deflowered_ is expressly passive, and doesn't necessarily work. That might depend on whether the former virgin considers their virginity to be something given away or something got rid of.

Comment: @Robusto: Given that note, I can only tend to agree; but it depends, for example the OP may want a distinction such as _'you're either a virgin or not'_, or otherwise _'you're either a virgin or a whore-type-thing'_. My instinct drew me to take the former view. I won't stand by the word as perfectly fitting, but it deserves to be contributed within this topic, with the potential to serve purpose, I think.

Comment: @Robusto once *deflowered*, forever *deflowered*.. that's the poignancy of the word's use relative to virginity (particularly for religious groups).

Answer (score 8):

*"Experienced"*

As in [the Jimi Hendrix song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4yZXb4aD2Q). Though it will only be clear in the right context.

*"Sexually expereienced"* is explicit, but not one word.

Answer (score 5):

Several answers from *[Love, sex, and marriage: a historical thesaurus](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lfSC4fpiW64C&lpg=PA294&dq=%22non-virgin%22&pg=PA294#v=onepage&q&f=false)* By Julie Coleman:

> **a woman who has had sex:**
>   unmaiden; sinner; maiden-wife-widow; damaged goods; fie-fie; amazon; non-virgin

I would go with *non-virgin*.

Comment: OK, "non-virgin" is clear, "unmaiden" is descriptive and likely to be understood even if people boggle at you, I'm tempted to try out "fie-fie" just for the fun of it, but "amazon" seems to come out of left field. What a fun book.

Comment: @dmckee It's fascinating and I would love to read it from cover to cover but it costs an arm and a leg and it certainly won't be in my local library.  I live in Oxford so I could go to the Bodleian but their website says it's stored off-site so I guess I'd have to request it from the librarian... and I don't think I could ask for a 'sex thesaurus' without blushing.

Answer (score 1):

**Coitized** is a polite way to say *had sexual intercourse* from the verb *coitize* from the same root as *coitus* (or maybe a verb derived from coitus).

A Rumanian women's erotic proverb says: 'God save us from being beaten by a blind man (who cannot see where his blows fall) and from being ***coitized*** by a lame one (who comes down hard on you).'

Answer (score -1):

Everyone is concentrating on the "have you had sex" aspect of the word virgin. Stop humanising the word, and look at its ACTUAL usage... virgin forest, virgin snow, virgin olive oil etc, yet they don't have sex to become non-virgin. They simply become IMPURE and SPOILED ETC.

Just because you don't want to describe your 80 year old gran as impure,it does not mean its an inaccurate way to describe her. Virgin in its general(as opposed to it specifically humanised usage) means "in its original state; never having been used". Since granny has been used and no longer in her original state (ignoring just getting old of course), she is impure.

Don't fanny about saying it's not a nice way to describe her. Is it accurate... yes or no?

Comment: -1 because of the higly culturally defined link between virginity and purity. The OP is not asking about any cultural reference, and the cultural link that established the use of the word for pure things is no longer present in many English-speaking societies. In a medical setting (which the OP seems to ask about) culturally defined values are inappropriate; many people would be seriously offended if a doctor, wanting to know whether they are sexually active, would ask them if they are pure or not, and some would get violent if the doctor were to ask them if they are _spoiled_.

Answer (score -4):

Playing off of [Anderson Silva's suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/antonym-for-virgin/28825#28825), you could use "sexed". It is classified in my dictionary as an adjective, but not quite as needed for this purpose. Its meaning would, therefore, be slightly ambiguous but it could work:

> He is sexed / He has been sexed

But a more serious answer is *non-celibate*:

> celibate — having or involving no sexual relations

And sometimes a more specific term applies:

- slut
- whore
- man-whore
- promiscuous
- wanton
- licentious
- debauched
- sensual
- experienced

And so on. You can always, of course, just say non-virgin which is actually how I most often hear people refer to, er, non-virgins. (Also, non-virgin wool, non-virgin olive oil, etc.)

Comment: Can't beat the scatter-gun effect! But I must just say that your headline verb **sex** prompted me to realise I'd completely forgotten why Jeanette Winterson titled her book [Sexing the Cherry](http://somanybooksblog.com/2009/01/31/sexing-the-cherry/). It refers to determining the sex of a cherry tree (like "sexing kittens"), and is nothing to do with human sexual congress.

Comment: @Fumble: I acknowledge that in the answer but common usage (at least in my area) is beginning to use _sexed_ as a humorous non-euphemism for _fucked_. The dictionaries haven't caught up yet -- and it is possible the usage will disappear -- but it is a legitimate option.

Comment: I hope not.  I might want to say - the male chickens are on the left, the female chickens are on the right, and the ones I haven't sexed yet are in the middle.