# Positive English word for Unmarried female non-virgin

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a positive word in the English language for an unmarried Female that has had sexual relations? What is a positive term for a non-virgin? I need the word for a poem title.

In late 1950's, a niece of a famous writer was free enough to express her love (at 16 years old). Having unashamedly chosen sex as a communicating device. I wrote about her, but found myself unable to title the piece. I don't believe there is a word in the English language for the above definition. The dictionary antonym for *virgin* is *married*!

**Q**: Is there any single positive word for an unmarried girl who has had sex?

Comment: A similar question has been answered here:
[Antonym for “Virgin”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/antonym-for-virgin)

Comment: I'm guessing about the closest you will get is "liberated woman".

Comment: 'Thoroughly modern'

Comment: *single girl/woman*........ Avoid *female* unless you are referring also to bats, salamanders, and lice - or unless you follow it by something like *person*.

Comment: Femme fatale covers a piece of the spectrum. You wouldn't seem to need a broadly inclusive term for a poem's title.

Comment: **Hippies** is a bit dated nowadays, but no one has ever associated celibacy with the name http://www.hipplanet.com/books/atoz/sex.htm

Comment: Person? Is there a word that comes to mind if you change from a girl to a boy?  Are you concentrating too much on the act and not enough on the decision.

Answer (score 2):

**Bachelorette** is a good one:

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bachelorette

Another option could be a **dame**.

It really depends through if you want to emphasize the non-virginness of her. Also depends on the age as well. Some more options [here.](http://www.freethesaurus.com/adult+female)

And also see the comment above on the article [Antonym for "Virgin"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/antonym-for-virgin).